# lookup values between date range

Tags: excel-formula

Good day,
I'm trying to use V&hLookup to get my values but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct formula.

I'm working of 2 sets of data (sheet1 and sheet2). Sheet1 the data is vertical (e.g. unique identifiers and dates) and sheet2 the dates are horizonal and values below. Both sheets have unique identifiers Vertically.
Question: On sheet1, I need to look up the values from sheet2, if there is not values then the formula must look at the next available value after the start date? I got the values as examples on sheet1 as to what it should be

E.g.

Sheet1

| **Key** | **Dates** | **Values** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01/01/2020 | *120.00* |
| 678910 | 01/02/2020 | *150.00* |
| 789456 | 01/03/2020 | *110.00* |

Sheet2

| **Key** | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | 03/04/2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 120.00 | 0.00 | 150.00 |
| 678910 | 0.00 | 120.50 | 130.00 |
| 789456 | 160.00 | 120.00 | 110.00 |

Thanks a million.

Comment: Wouldn't the value of `678910` at `01/02/2020` be `120.50`?

Answer (score 2):

Edited answer: suggested solution using `MATCH(search_value,match_range,1)` in combination with INDEX gave wrong results.

The following should do:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$4,            
       MATCH(A5,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,0), 
       MATCH( 
             MIN(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$D$1>=B5,Sheet2!$B$1:$D$1,"")),
             Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,
             0))
```

Enter with `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel versions.

The row is found matching the `Key`-value and the column is found by matching the column where the date value in Sheet2 headers greater than or equal to search date value.

[image]

And when using Tables:

```
=INDEX(Table3,
       MATCH([@Key],Table3[Key],0),
       MATCH(
             MIN(IFERROR(IF(--Table3[#Headers]>=[@Dates],--Table3[#Headers]),9^9)),
             --Table3[#Headers],
             0))
```

Where I needed to workaround the date headers becoming text instead of number values by adding leading `--` to the value/range.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The value for 789456 at 01/03/2020 must be 110.00. The formula must use the next date after the 01/03/2020 and not before.

Comment: Sorry, see updated answer which has different logic, giving desired result.